# How can i reconnect websocket connection when it is closed using angular2-websocket in Angular2 Application?

Tags: javascript, angular, websocket

Iam new to angular2 framework. I used angular2-websocket plugin to use websockets in my project. My scenario is , if once the socket connection is closed it is not reconnecting when the socket is opened at server side. How could i do it using [angular2-websocket](https://github.com/afrad/angular2-websocket)?? How can i reconnect to my socket when it is opened??

Here is my app.component.ts code snippet

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { $WebSocket, WebSocketSendMode } from 'angular2-websocket/angular2-websocket';
import { WebsocketService } from '../../../services/websocket.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-init',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private websocket:WebsocketService) { }
  ngOnInit() {
      this.fnGraphInit("ws://10.1.40.117:5555");
  }


fnGraphInit(url){

let ws = new $WebSocket(url);
    ws.getDataStream().subscribe(
      (msg) => { 
        console.log(msg.data);

      (msg) => {
        console.log("error", msg);

      },
      () => {
        console.log("complete");

      }
    );
}

}
}
```

Please help me in solving this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using WebSocketConfig:

```
const webSocketConfig = { reconnectIfNotNormalClose: true } as WebSocketConfig;

this.ws                  = new $WebSocket(url, null, webSocketConfig);
```